# Scroll to top with estimated cell heights

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

What is the proper way of scrolling a `UITableView` to the top when using estimated cell heights by implementing `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

I noticed that the usual method does not necessarily scroll to the top if there is enough estimation error.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:animated];
```

Comment: Umm that's not the usual method.

Comment: @Desdenova What is? I want to scroll to the top, not the first `indexPath`.

Comment: Scrolling to a row (NSIndexPath) is the only documented Apple way of scrolling. Setting content offset is messing with the underlying scroll view.

Comment: @Desdenova It's not an "underlying" scroll view. The fact that `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` and has `contentOffset` is public API. Where have you read that we shouldn't use `contentOffset`?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue (I wasn't trying to scroll the tableview to the top manually but the view wasn't scrolling correctly when tapping the status bar).

The only way I've come up with to fix this is to ensure in your `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method you return the *actual* height if you know it.

My implementation caches the results of calls to `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for efficiency , so I'm simply looking up this cache in my estimations to see if I already know the real height.

I think the issue comes from `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` being called in preference over `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` even when scrolling upwards over cells that have already been rendered. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

How about `tableView.scrollToRow`? Solved the issue for me.

**Swift 3 example**:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: This worked for me. All the other methods to do with content offset ran into hard to solve edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

how about this snippet code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0f animations:^{
    [_tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO]; //1
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    _tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero; //2
}];
```

1. scroll to offset that calculated by estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath
2. setContentOffsetZero

inspiration from https://github.com/caoimghgin/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

```
let point = { () -> CGPoint in
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        return CGPoint(x: -tableView.adjustedContentInset.left, y: -tableView.adjustedContentInset.top)
    }
    return CGPoint(x: -tableView.contentInset.left, y: -tableView.contentInset.top)
}()

for section in (0..<tableView.numberOfSections) {
    if 0 < tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
        // Find the cell at the top and scroll to the corresponding location
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section),
                            at: .none,
                            animated: true)
        if tableView.tableHeaderView != nil {
            // If tableHeaderView != nil then scroll to the top after the scroll animation ends
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
            }
        }
        return
    }
}
tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to how your code works for people who see this in the future.